# Can distutils install the module/package as an executable script?

Tags: python, deployment, installation, distutils, setup.py

I'm using distutils.core.setup for the first time. I got it to install my module in /usr/lib/python/site-packages.

If I run python from any directory and do `import my_module` it all works great.

However, I need to run my module as script. It's not intended as a library, but rather as an application. If I run from terminal `python my_module` it does not find the file.

I wanted to make an executable script that will run my module and put a sym link to it in /usr/bin, but that seems like a hacky way to solve this. I presume distutils has something to install your module as an executable script, except I wasn't able to find it. Could someone please point me to an example or doc file for this?

Edit: Also, if this is not the right way to distribute a python application, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
distutils.core.setup(scripts=['myprogram'])
```

instead of `py_modules=['mymodule.py']`

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I looked at this and tried it. And indeed my setup.py now installs the main script of my code in /usr/local/bin. My problem is now that this particular script is looking for the other modules in my source tree, which are not in /usr/local/bin. I'm thinking I should have only a symlink in /usr/local/bin, not the actual script. Any idea how to do this through distutils?

Comment: Actually, never mind my previous comment. I figured I should have had all my imports referencing the full package path. :) All working! Thank you!